# VS Compiler warning 4239 caused by default argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have this declaration of a method and faced to a VS2015 compiler warning C4239:

> warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'default argument': conversion from 'std::shared_ptr' to 'std::shared_ptr &'
>
> > note: A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue

`void checkMe(shared_ptr<string>& param = shared_ptr<string>());`

This [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C4239)&rd=true) article says it is a /W4 warning. Fun fact: /W3 is set.

To be honest, I'm not a pro regarding default arguments, but in the implementation is no real use of having an empty instance of the `shared_ptr` without usage afterwards. But I'd rather understand the issue than adjusting  the functionality.

How and why then can I get rid of the warning? Or is there any legal way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You're initializing a non-const reference with a temporary. This doesn't look right. What's the intent here?

Comment: What @BartekBanachewicz says plus why does this function need a default at all ?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz yep - that the warning just said - VS has this non-standard extension since the beginning - one of many

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Intention? This is an old grown project and the signature actually has another argument. So I can only guess that this method had only the other once and for compatibility reasons the second had to came up with a default value. No docs at all.... But thank you all, I will correct this, since there is no real value in initialization at this point.